# Testing google-maps

Tags: android, google-maps, testing

I have a small question. How can I test an application which uses the google-maps api?
I am looking for a tutorial that describes how to write test for checking the longitude, latitude and ranges of two points.
I just found some tutorials how to write google-maps application, but now I want to test it.
Especially the format of the longitudes and latitudes, because when I print them out they get represented with that E7 style and I can't see the whole coordinate.

Comment: In order to verify the value of latitude and longitude,you can put you values as (xx°xx'xx.x"N,0xx°xx'xx.xx"E) in google maps search text box and it will directly result in your location.In this way you can validate your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The E7 is just an integer representation of the latitude / longitude if you want to get the float value of that just use:

```
float latitude = latitudeE7 / 1E7
```

if you want to check the values you can put for example:

```
Log.d("TAG", "Latitude: " + String.valueOf(latitude) );
```

Comment: Thank you, this could help me a lot.

Comment: the decimal places is the precision on the position, but I think Google Maps works with 7 decimal positions (That's the reason for the 1E7 which means 10000000)